# position absolute inside position relative gives element scope in parent

Tags: html, css

I was working on a site and have a parent element with `position:relative` that has child elements with `position:absolute`. What's strange to me is that with the positions I mentioned, the child elements seem to still recognize their parent and have scope within it.

heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83mLv3un/) to demonstrate what happens.

This actually ended up working to my advantage, but I'd like understand what happens to cause this.

Comment: This is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Absolutely positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) are placed in relation to the first positioned parent element. It is acting as it should.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the definition of `position: absolute` then it will make more sense.

absolute position: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element